# cairo dock cant find plugins?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, cairo-dock

Well I restarted my computer trying to fix a cpu issue.When I loaded back up my cairo dock says cant find its plugins so it closed out?anyone know how to fix this as well? once again I just,i guess you can say,upgraded to 12.04

Answer (score 2):

I got the cairo dock fixed. I removed cairo dock completely from terminal,then reinstalled. To remove cairo dock and plugins open terminal and put this in first-

```
sudo apt-get purge cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

that removes it completely.If cairo dock is on your desktop right click it and click quit first to get it off your desktop.

After the removal is done in terminal copy and paste these three commands in one at a time-

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cairo-dock-team/ppa  
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins
```

Comment: I tried that as well with no luck. Still "no plugins". How did you remove it completely?